# Using ajax within an IFrame

Tags: php, ajax, iframe, yii

In my site I have an iframe, which contains a Chtml::ajaxButton. I have found many posts regarding this problem, but couldn't find a solution.

What I think is important to highlight, is that this iframe is not being used to send data to a domain which is different from the host page.

**view.php**

```
        <div style="height: 385px; width: 350px; overflow: hidden">
            <?php $url = "displayMessages?league_id=".$model->id; ?>
            <iframe src="<?php print $url?>" width="350" height="385">
            </iframe>
        </div>
```

**LeaguesController.php**

```
public function actionDisplayMessages()
{
    if(isset($_GET['league_id'])){
        $selectedLeague = $_GET['league_id'];
        $league = LigasDeAmigos::model()->findByPk((int)$selectedLeague);
        $user = (int)Yii::app()->user->id;
        $this->renderPartial('leagueWallMessages', array(
                                                    'model'=>$league,
                                                    'messages'=>$league->messages,
                                                    'user'=>$user,
        ));
    }       
}
```

**LeagueWallMessages.php**

```
<?php 
    echo CHtml::ajaxButton(
        "Compartir", CController::createUrl('leagues/insertComment',
    array(
        'league_id'=>$model->id)),
        array(
            'success' => "js: function(){ alert('Success!!'); }",
            'type' => 'post',
        ),
        array(
            'id'=>'idButtonShare',
            'style'=>'width:70px;height:40px; align:right;'
        )
    );
?>
```

This button in LeagueWallMessages.php, when clicked, doesn't fire any action. What might cause this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had forgotten to have the button within a form definition. I placed the button and other contents within a form, and changed the button for a `ajaxSubmitButton`.